# Chinese old scroll writing seal marks

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

I would like to know if anyone can translate the red reign seal marks and wording on these old scrolls.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3eLD.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdijH.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYhKq.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

#### Seal transcriptions only

[image: 1]

> 張氏
>
> House of 張 (Mandarin: **Zhāng**)
>
> 亦（農）止（之）鉩（璽）
>
> Seal of Yìnóng

[image: 2]

> ⿱陳土（陳）躍（中）
>
> Chén Yuèzhōng